# Why 0.85em font size?

Tags: css, font-size

I've seen a lot of sites and especially the template project in MVC3 use 0.85em as their body font-size in the stylesheet. My question is why? Isn't setting the body font-size to 1em(16px) or 0.625(10px) make it easier for calculating? While 0.85em will result in the default font-size of 13.6px (assuming that the default font-size is 16px)

Comment: This was a design decision and doesn't really have a valid answer.

Comment: It's like asking why you picked that gravatar, or why Stack Overflow's color scheme is made up of grays, blues and oranges.

Comment: Why *is* Stack Overflow's color scheme made up of grays, blues, and oranges?